# ActiveRecord in Rails 4 without environment specific databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

i want to know if there is a way of using activerecord without the environment specific databases (development, test, production).

the reason for this is that i am using mongodb as main database (mongoid), but i need to access an external oracle database and would like to use active record.

the problem is that when i enable active record in my application.rb:

```
require 'active_record/railtie'
```

it tries to connect to development database (which won't exist).

is there a way around this? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try requiring only active record, like this:

```
require "active_record"
```

And then load the `database.yml` file manually like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.configurations = YAML.load_file(File.expand_path('../database.yml', __FILE__))
```

Then you can remove the development, test and production databases from `database.yml`.